# Makefile wildcard with variable inside

Tags: makefile, wildcard

I am trying to get all the files inside each folder with Makefile:

```
Test = $(wildcard */)

install: all
  @for dir in $(TEST); do \
    echo $$dir; \
    echo $(wildcard $$dir); \
  done
```

First echo outputs correctly: folder1/ folder2/ folder3/ but when used with wildcard in second echo I am getting empty output (each folder contains many files).
Any suggestions why this doesn't work and how to archive this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$(wildcard)` is **make function**, which is evaluated once while makefile is parsed.

`dir` is a **shell variable**, which exists only *when receipt is evaluated* (using shell).

Because *make* is unaware about *shell* variables, pattern in `$(wildcard $$dir)` is interpreted by *make* literally: `$$dir`.

If you want to output list of files in a directory pointed by `dir` variable, you should use *shell* utilities. E.g. `ls $$dir`.

Comment: I tried `echo $(shell ls $$dir);` and it outputs `folder1/` `folder2/` `folder3/`

Could you provide an example?

Comment: I need to use result of `ls $$dir` inside `INSTALL`. E.g.:
`$(INSTALL) $(ls $$dir) $(<path>)`. Is it possible?

Comment: Try `$(INSTALL) $$dir/* $(path)`.